# Hyperlink detection in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook web addins that involves extracting all hyperlinks from the mail message. I am currently doing it by getting all `a` tag elements.

```
var htmlParser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(asyncResult.value, "text/html");
var urls = htmlParser.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

However, I found out that Outlook for PC displays text as a hyperlink as long as it contains `www.`, even though the text is not meant to be a hyperlink. For example, I tried sending myself an email with `www.example.com` as the content and I ensured that it is not a hyperlink when I sent it out.

[image]

In Outlook on the web, the text is indeed not a hyperlink.

[image]

But then in Outlook for PC, the text was displayed as a hyperlink automatically. Since I did not send it out as a hyperlink, it does not have an `a` tag and hence my addin could not extract this "hyperlink". Is there a way to also extract these "hyperlinks" in a mail message?

[image]

Comment: You can use the following - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-LinkRevealer

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [getEntitiesByType API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#getEntitiesByType_entityType_) to get any URL entities identified in the mail body. A sample API call is:

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.getEntitiesByType(Office.MailboxEnums.EntityType.Url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Outlook add-in - Mail add-in for a read scenario which finds and parses all links in the body of an email. Here's the documentation/sample @ https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-LinkRevealer

Comment: Thanks, but it uses the method of getting all a tag elements as well, which is what I am already doing now and does not solve my problem.

Comment: hmm... if its the case, i would suggest you to create an issue at the sample issues tab. Here's the link - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-LinkRevealer/issues